# Android Tablet UI issue

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation-drawer

I wanna make friendly design for the all Android devices. I made design for the Smartphones using the Navigation Drawer like on the image 1. I also want to make design for the Tablet devices like on the image 2 without using the Navigation Drawer. How can i make this? Do I need to detect a device programmatically and if it is the Tablet device i will use a alternative layout for Tablet device?

Here is my layout for Tablet devices( folder layout-sw600dp) without using the left drawer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_list"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/state_listview_left"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/llBasketBarCenter"
    style="@style/StyleInfoPanelBasket"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                style="@style/StyleBarText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/payable" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvCenterPanelSum"
                 style="@style/StyleBarSum"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvCenterPanelSumCoins"
                 style="@style/StyleBarCoins"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvCenterPanelSum"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCenterPanelSum" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvCenterPanelSumValue"
                 style="@style/StyleBaCurrency"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvCenterPanelSum"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCenterPanelSumCoins"
                 android:text="@string/currency" />

             <RelativeLayout 
                style="@style/StyleCartIcon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCenterPanelSumValue"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCountInCart"
                    style="@style/StyleCartCount"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                style="@style/StyleTextNext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onGoToTheBasketClick"
                android:text="@string/in_basket" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/state_listview_left"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

 <LinearLayout 
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

![enter image description here][1]

Here is my layout for the others devices with using the left drawer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/llBasketBarCenter"
    style="@style/StyleInfoPanelBasket"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                style="@style/StyleBarText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/payable" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvCenterPanelSum"
                 style="@style/StyleBarSum"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvCenterPanelSumCoins"
                 style="@style/StyleBarCoins"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvCenterPanelSum"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCenterPanelSum" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tvCenterPanelSumValue"
                 style="@style/StyleBaCurrency"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvCenterPanelSum"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCenterPanelSumCoins"
                 android:text="@string/currency" />

             <RelativeLayout 
                style="@style/StyleCartIcon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvCenterPanelSumValue"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCountInCart"
                    style="@style/StyleCartCount"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                style="@style/StyleTextNext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onGoToTheBasketClick"
                android:text="@string/in_basket" />

</RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/state_listview_left"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

 <LinearLayout 
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Before people will assist you'll need to post what you have tried otherwise the question will be downvoted. (I don't downvote questions fyi so this isn't me)

Comment: Using relative layout will save you some time

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I  really have not known I must type all the my code that I tried do before asking. I corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice to use different layout for Tablet and smartphone , due to different size of smartphone(mega,etc) and tablet(mini,etc) I preferably say to use different layout will be a good practice.check phone and tablet with this code sample.

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE ||(getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE ){
            //in tablet
        } else {
            //in Phone

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your manifest to decide for which you want to make your app

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Google's recommendations and use fragments. Look this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html